# C# Adding XML atribute in an EXISTING element

Tags: c#, xml

In my XML document i want to add two strings as atributes

```
        XElement myele = new XElement("Custom_value");
        myele.Add(new XAttribute("name", type));
        myele.Add(new XAttribute("value", value));
```

How do I add these 2 atributes into the EXISTING Custom field.

Comment: you mean u have the **XElement myEle** and you want to add attribute on **myEle**

Comment: new XElement("Custom_value") already exists?

Comment: What? Your code already shows how to add an `XAttribute` to an "existing" `XElement`. After `XElement myele = new XElement("Custom_value");` the `XElement` exists. Or are you asking how to *retrieve* an (existing) `XElement` from another (existing) `XElement`? For example the root of an `XDocument`?

Comment: try this: myele.SetAttributeValue("name", type); also make sure type is not null otherwise attribute will not be available

Comment: @MARC I understand you to say that you have an xml file that has an element `<Custom></Custom>` and you want to move the contents of attribute `name` and the attribute `value` into the element `Custom` for display. So you want to write this?? `...<Custom>abc 0.12</Custom>...` Is this correct?? If so you will have to read the contents of the existing file and rewrite it to a new file. The new file can have the same name as the old file and be stored in the same location.

Comment: Did you load your XML file content into a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) object? If so, you can play around with the [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348975.aspx) method to find the existing `XElement` you want and then just add the `XAttributes` you want. (Or set them, if they already exist.)

Comment: @FrankPytel Yes you understand me correctly. So the only way to do it is to create a new file, then copy the contents of the old file into the new file.... then append the atributes then save it all to the new file with the same name?

Comment: @MARC That's what I would do. That's of course assuming you have the permissions. This is your program? If it's a third party vendor you may only have permissions to access it through their SDK

Comment: So could you explain how i would go about it? @FrankPytel

Comment: @Corak I load it as follows i use foreach (XMLNODE in mynodes.childnodes) then add them to a datagridview by atribute.

Comment: I just went and used a normal txt file. But thanks for the attempt guys :-) much appreciated.